# SQL round percent up to nearest .1

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal, rounding

I have a columns of percentages and i want them to always round up to the nearest .1

for example

```
.005 --> .1
.11 --> .2
.3256 -->.4
.6797 -->.7
```

I am trying ceiling and floor, but they give me all whole numbers

I have tried this, but it still rounds as it normally would work

round(n * 10, 0) / 10 as [nearest 0.10]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Sql-server tag added

Comment: If this is `SQL Server`, why do I see `MySQL` tag there???  They are two completely different products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use `ceiling()` and arithmetic:

```
select ceiling(percentage * 10) / 10.0
```

Comment: It performs 3 operations: Multiplication, Division, and Ceiling. Always use internal functions provided by the software/framework.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, with modular arithmetic:

```
DECLARE @a DECIMAL(5,5) = 0.000005 --insert your number here

PRINT ROUND(@a, 1) + CASE WHEN @a % 0.1 < 0.05 AND @a % 0.1 > 0 THEN 0.1 ELSE 0 END
```

This tests to see if the remainder when divided by 0.1 is between 0 and 0.05 (meaning it rounded down), and adds 0.1 to the rounded value if so.

Answer (score -1):

round() function can be the easiest option available.

```
select round(1.02345443,2) from dual
```

where the 1st argument is the input number and the second digit is digits after decimal point.

Please refer to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) official doc for more reference.